# Why is method with int parameter used instead of method with Short parameter?

Tags: java, boxing, autoboxing

Considered this code and using Java 1.8:

```
public class Main {

    public static void go(Long n) {
        System.out.println("Long ");
    }

    public static void go(Short n) {
        System.out.println("Short ");
    }

    public static void go(int n) {
        System.out.println("int ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short y = 6;
        long z = 7;
        go(y);
        go(z);
    }

}
```

Why JVM calls method go(int) while calling go(y), where y is of short primitive type?

[Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) says, short should be boxed to Short object. Could anyone explain what is really happening while calling the method go(y), where y is of short primitive type?

The output of this whole thing is

```
int
Long
```

Comment: Widening beats boxing.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks for your answer. And sorry for duplicate, didnt find the mentioned question as I was looking for anything connected to boxing or unboxing